# Hanging upside down

Tags: strength, bodyweight-exercises

I want to get my legs to be strong enough to hang upside down by holding my entire body with just my feet.

Couldn't find anything other than just some tibialis antirior dumbell curls and exercises with machine that i don't have. Are there any other options ?

Answer (score 1):

There is tool named powerball - it was discovered to help astronauts to train, and going into space - every pound costs a lot. The tool uses gyroscopic force to which your muscles needs to resist. I'm using it for forearms training, but I know that there are straps - look for "powerball foot trainer". [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeHcpoqtK-8) is video how "the training" can look like. It is a bit noisy, a specially with higher speed, so watching TV is rather not an option.

Besides that any exercise for front of leg is good for you. I would use bands for that - they can be more convenient then putting weight on your toes.

Comment: This has the potential to be a good answer, but I'm suspicious of links to a particular product without an explanation of why it makes for a good answer. And could you elaborate on what sorts of "front of leg" exercises they ought to do with the bands?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I understand your point, edited a bit my post, with better video. This stuff is with me for very long time, and is really helpful. I don't have any interest in promoting it. Just good, simple tool - that is all.